# follow javascript redirection with python

Tags: javascript, python, redirect

I am trying to automate authentication into a website using the login page. The sticking point is that after submitting the login username & password form I am redirected to a new (middleman) page where there is a javascript redirect to the website i want to access. 
the source looks like this:

```
<script>
top.location=url;
</script>
```

How can I follow this redirect? I have tried js wrapper Python libraries but did not find a solution yet. Code snippets are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.location instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i not building the website. i am trying to bypass it as a user. the login page is https://www.rottentomatoes.com/user/account/login-iframe.